Distributed points with Geometry Nodes on an animated armature popping in and out?
I'm trying to generate instances using geometry nodes on an object with an armature. The problem is that any pose changes make the instances unstable:

I get the underlying issue, geometry nodes distributes points after the armature, so it treats any change to the object like new geometry. Is there any way to "lock" it?
I tried separating it, by distributing the points before armature in the modifier stack, using a capture attribute for the points, and then having a second Geometry Nodes setup after armature modifier to instance points with that attribute. But it doesn't seem to work. I also found a similar question here, but the solution to use Raycast node doesn't work for my use case.
Does anyone know if it's possible at all?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KkZRnCHR18B9flbSFph1zeSx5W6K50vf/view?usp=sharing

can u pls provide your blend file. I tried it out and it worked for me.

thx for providing the file. For me it looks like a bug...So you could go to Help->report a bug.

I've had a play and can't find a getaround (That's not to say someone else won't).. I resorted to the old toolkit. 1 Particle System all on frame one, rendering 'Collection', to scatter. 2 'Make instances Real' in the particle modifier, then mod. applied. 3 Object mode, instances selected, mesh active, vertex parenting to (default nearest) triangle, (can all be done at once). If that's acceptable, could post as an answer.. Non-deforming instances, stuck to surface.

yeah, those are nice solutions, but I was hoping to find out if there's a way of fixing it within geometry nodes. Using a particle system works, but it's overall much more limited than nodes. Thx for the suggestions tho.
